# Why did The Hand harvest this substance in Daredevil, when this other substance seemed important in the Defenders?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015, the-defenders-2017

Back in Daredevil, we learn that The Hand is

> farming blood from people, and it appears it has something to do with their resurrection spell/ritual.

But then in The Defenders we find out that The Hand's

> secret ingredient for immortality is dragon bone dust. But if that's what they needed, what was the point of all the blood?

Comment: Can't the formula require both?

Comment: @JDoe Man, I dunno, that's why I'm asking. Does the show back that up?

Comment: My guess is they needed both. We see evidence for blood farming in Iron Fist as well as Daredevil. Blood is just much easier to come by then dragon bones. I have no actual evidence to back this up right now though

Comment: Is blood required for resurrection? Isn't it related to the Black Sky (whose ritual may or may not involve resurrection)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They were used for two different rituals.

The "substance" being mined in *The Defenders* is what The Hand, and presumably the masters of K'un Lun, have been using for centuries to keep themselves alive, and what allows their resurrection to happen. What's under New York City appears to be the last major reserve of the substance outside of K'un Lun, so the Hand is eager to get at it, because their supply is running low. Prior to that, they must have had stockpiles of it from previous mining operations, so they were content to leave what's under NYC alone until they needed it.

In *Daredevil*, we are seeing the efforts of what seems to be Alexandria's faction of The Hand, focusing on her vision to bring about the Black Sky. (Note that Madame Gao doesn't ever seem to take a direct role in the events of *Daredevil*) This is a special ritual, different from the resurrection ritual, and requires more resources. Not only does it require the blood being drained from the captives, but it also uses up the last of the Hand's reserves of the substance. Alexandria believes the Black Sky will help them finally return to K'un Lun, so she's willing to put all of those resources into a single ritual to bring back the Black Sky.

Comment: Reading this now, I'm reminded of the episode in Defenders where they have a flash back at the start of the episode to when they resurrect Electra. There is a shot of some guy sprinkling a grey powder onto a bowl of blood. I never really though about it at the time, but I guess now that the powder was "the substance", and the blood is just vehicle for it. Perhaps they need both to make the resurrection ritual work.